# How Do I Display Text on a LineSeries Plot?

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I'm trying to print the value of a point onto the plot, but the documentation provided is incomplete or confusing. I understand that the TrackerFormatString value can do something similar, but I want the text to always be on the plot that dynamically changes with different values. Is there something that I perhaps overlooked or maybe I could look into?

```
var series1 = new LineSeries { Title = "Stage I", MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle, Smooth = true, TrackerFormatString = "Stage I\nYear: {2:0.0}\n{4:0.0} %" };
//let's say I have a line series like this
//I need to enter some sort of text on the plot that has the values of the below points:
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0.0, 100.0));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 82.3));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 59.2)); 
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(5, 47.7));
```

[This is what I have:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4GSe.png)

[This is what I need:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK6Xj.png)

Any sort of help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, you want to add annotation?

Answer (score 1):

You can add annotations to your plot. For displaying text use `TextAnnotation`.

Add the annotations to your model, providing a `DataPoint` for the location and the `Text` for the text to display. For example

```
yourModel.Annotations.Add(new TextAnnotation { TextPosition = new DataPoint(DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(now), wert), Text = "82.3%" });
```